# How to save nested json in database

Tags: java, json, database, database-design

I have a nested `json` containing `arrays` and I have to save it into the database. I'm converting `Json` to Object using `GSON` library and then adding fields to `database`. But I have a problem as `Json` is nested and has arrays, how to save same named fields into database ?

`JSON`:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": "B",
      "c": [
        {
          "d": "DD",
          "e": [
            {
              "f": "F",
              "g": "G",
              "h": "H"
            },
            {
              "f": "F",
              "g": "G",
              "h": "H"
            },
            {
              "f": "F",
              "g": "G",
              "h": "H"
            },
            {
              "f": "F",
              "g": "G",
              "h": "H"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "d": "DDD",
          "e": [
            {
              "f": "F",
              "g": "G",
              "h": "H"
            },
            {
              "f": "F",
              "g": "G",
              "h": "H"
            },
            {
              "f": "F",
              "g": "G",
              "h": "H"
            },
            {
              "f": "F",
              "g": "G",
              "h": "H"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Problem comes while adding fields `d,e,f,g,h`. 
What I followed is adding fields as

```
d0,e0,f00,g00,h00
      f01,g01,h01
      f02,g02,h02


d1,e1,f10,g10,h10
      f11,g11,h11
      f12,g12,h12
```

and so on...

is this the correct way to save ?

I hope not, because while retrieving and creating json again, there will be more logic required to get f11 and assign it to 1st item in e's array.

Can any one suggest a better way to save into database ?

Comment: How about saving as BLOB?

Comment: @JavaUser no, I need all the values as fields in database, 'coz I need to make some aggregate functions for analytics